# Method runs once when called and gives same output when called again

Tags: java, methods, jbutton, jtextfield

```
class RPSAppenderAction implements ActionListener
   { 
        Random random = new Random();
        int compChoice = random.nextInt(3);
        int[] outcome = new int[3];

        public void rockGame()
       {
           if (compChoice == 0)
           {
               txaResults.append("Rock vs Rock equals a tie! \n");
               outcome[2]++;
               Tie.setText("Total " + outcome[2]);
           }
           else if (compChoice == 1)
           {
               txaResults.append("Paper Covers Rock (Computer Wins)! \n");
               outcome[1]++;
               CompWins.setText("Total " + outcome[1]);
           }
           else if (compChoice == 2)
           {    
               txaResults.append("Rock smashes scissors (You Win) \n");
               outcome[0]++;
               UserWins.setText("Total " + outcome[0]);
           } 
       }

       public void paperGame()
       {
           if (compChoice == 0)
           {
               txaResults.append("Paper covers rock (You win)! \n"); 
               outcome[0]++;
               UserWins.setText("Total " + outcome[0]);
           }
           else if (compChoice == 1)
           {
               txaResults.append("Paper vs Paper equals a tie \n");
               outcome[2]++;
               Tie.setText("Total " + outcome[2]);
           }
           else if (compChoice == 2)
           {    
               txaResults.append("Scissors cuts Paper(You Lose) \n"); 
               outcome[1]++;
               CompWins.setText("Total " + outcome[1]);
           } 
       }

       public void scissorsGame()
       {
           if (compChoice == 0)
           {
               txaResults.append("Rock smashes scissors (You Lose)! \n"); 
               outcome[1]++;
               CompWins.setText("Total " + outcome[1]);
           }
           else if (compChoice == 1)
           {
               txaResults.append("Scissors cut paper (You Win)! \n");;
               outcome[0]++;
               UserWins.setText("Total " + outcome[0]);
           }
           else if (compChoice == 2)
           {    
               txaResults.append("The game is a tie! \n"); 
               outcome[2]++;
               Tie.setText("Total " + outcome[2]);
           } 
       }

       @Override
       public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent click )
       {
           Object source = click.getSource();

           if (source == btnRock)
           {
               rockGame();
           }

           if (source == btnPaper)
           {
               paperGame();
           }

           if (source == btnScissors)
           {
               scissorsGame();
           }

       } 
    }
```

Here I have an actionListener so whenever someone clicks on the respective JButton for rock, paper or scissors the rockGame(), paperGame() or scissorGame() methods are called. However, the first time through when I select say rock for instance, the program will run correctly but if I hit rock again then the output will be the same every time (same txaResult appended to JScrollPane and same outcome[] count in the JTextField). It's taking the same result from the first time the method was called instead of calling a different instance of that method for each run. Is there a way I can have the respective method be called again when someone clicks on a JButton instead of just using the first result? Thanks. I've been on this problem for a while and can't think of anything

Comment: Hint: your random selection doesn't happen in a method.

Comment: @shmosel hmm. So i brought my array and compChoice into each method but now my outcome[] isn't incrementing properly. It will go to 1 and then not increment any further

Comment: @shmosel got it to work! Thankssssss

Comment: @BallaBaby Please answer your question below through the advice you got from shmosel.